# Invariance of Decomposition of Invariant Functional

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, topological-groups, group-actions

Let $Q$ a locally compact group acting on a locally compact space $X$ on the left. Let $\mathcal{A}$ a Banach space of bounded continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ and $m\in\mathcal{A}^{\ast}$ a bounded linear functional which is invariant under the action of $Q$, i.e. $m(gf)=m(f)$ for all $f\in\mathcal{A}$, where:
$$gf(x):=f(g^{-1}\cdot x)\quad\forall f\in\mathcal{A},g\in Q,x\in X$$
Assume that $m=m_{1}-m_{2}+\mathbf{i} m_{3}-\mathbf{i} m_{4}$, where $m_{1},m_{2},m_{3}$ and $m_{4}$ in $\mathcal{A}^{\ast}$ are positive functionals, i.e. $m_{j}(f)\geq 0$ for all $1\leq j\leq 4$ and $f\geq 0$.

> **Question:** is $m_{j}$ invariant under $G$?
>   It seems somehow obvious but I have not managed to write it down for some reason.

In case you want to know: I am given a locally compact group $G$ and closed subgroups $H,Q\leq G$, a $Q$-invariant functional $m$ on $\mathscr{C}_{b}^{lu}(G/H)$, which are the bounded continuous functions such that the orbit maps $g\mapsto gf$ are continuous. I need $m$ to be normalized and positive, so that for $X:=G/H$ I use $\mathscr{C}_{b}(X)^{\ast}\cong\mathcal{M}(\beta X)$, the space of complex Radon measures on the Stone-Čech compactification. These functionals I can decompose as needed and I want to use the positive part only.

Comment: I read somewhere that you need to take self adjoint part of $m$ and the remaining part. And represent each part as the difference of positive functionals, then you'll get the desired invariance.

Comment: Oho! This sounds interesting. I am not sure what taking the self-adjoint part means exactly. Can you specify the "somewhere" part in your comment any further? I would be in great debt towards you. Thank you.

Comment: I know from operator theory that self-adjoint part of operator $A$ is an operator $0.5 (A+A^*)$. So we need to define the notion of involution on $\mathcal{A}^*$. May be it is $m^*(f)=\overline{m(f^*)}$

Comment: @Norbert Fyi: the only natural involution on $\mathcal{A}$ is imo $f^{\ast}(x)=\overline{f(x)}$, i.e. conjugation. Hence the involution you proposed is the identity. I would drop the ${}^{\ast}$ inside the functional, in which case the self-adjoint part you mentioned is $\Re m$, which I know is invariant. Just thought you might want to know.

Comment: Do you want to prove invariance for all representations of $m$ in terms of positive functionals OR for some representation?

Comment: My goal is to find A non-trivial positive functional. What I did was to find $m$ in a first step, then I did decompose $\Re m$ (which is invariant) and now I would like to find that the positive part (which is non-trivial as $m(1)=1$) is invariant.

Comment: May be you could fingd something useful [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/ncg/paststudents/RSB_bsthesis.pdf) on the page 44

Comment: Thanks for the link. This might indeed be what I need (i.e. the explicit construction of a positive functional from a given one), as it seems to not be obvious that the positive and negative parts need to be invariant. All I have is that they agree on the subspace $\{gf-f;g\in G,f\in\mathcal{A}\}$. This space is not dense or anything and I guess one can extend such functionals in many ways (in particular in non-invariant ways). If I find something else, I'll post an answer.